# Redirect to a category within Zendesk after JWT SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, jwt, zendesk

I'm trying to use JWT to do SSO in Zendesk.  I can't find a way to direct the user to a specific category/page within my Zendesk account directly in the call to authenticate and log in.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this: 
https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816-Setting-up-single-sign-on-with-JWT-JSON-Web-Token-

In particular, the section concerning the return_to parameter in the URL.